# emacs find file in project on a big project

Tags: emacs

In vim, there is this amazing plugin called command-t, that lets you fuzzy-search through all the files in your project. We have a fairly large rails app with a ton of files, and it is able to handle it pretty much without any slowdown at all.

tried a few things (like ffip, textmate.el's command-t, and rinari's rinari-find-in-project). The UI is great (I <3 flex), but the problem they all have is on a large project, the performance is bad to the point of being unusable.

Currently I am making more use of rinaris navigation commands and ido-find-file. Between the two of them it is a usable setup, but it would be nice to have a crazy fast fuzzy find in project.

Does anyone know of a more performant script then what I have tried?

Comment: Here are some more packages which do something like this: http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/LocateFilesAnywhere

Comment: Try M-x anything, if you haven't done so, for comparison

Comment: I posted my anything based solution below.  Let me know if you have any problems with it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A github rep for my concoction is here: https://github.com/lewang/anything-project-files

I added a few more anything sources so that anything-project-find can be a drop-in replacement for "C-x b".  So the idea is when you hit "C-x b" you are completing against existing buffers, recent files through recentf (personally I hack it to use "session.el" instead, but it's a small diff), files in current dir, files in current project.  I find it pretty handy.

I've used this for a while, but it's not well tested, so please report any bugs you find.

Comment: This is pretty great :) my problem is our project is around 6.5k files, and anything (at least in my laptop) chokes at that amount of stuff. Going to try it on my i7 at work, and if that doesn't work, make several different sources scoped to certain dirs (for example,  tests are 1.5k of the total files) thanks a ton for this though, pretty sure this is the track I am going to go down

Comment: My project has 2.5k "interesting" files.  I just grew it to 7.5k for a test and everything works fine.  Loads in about the same amount of time -- about 0.5 seconds on my 2.5 GHz core-2-duo MBP.

Comment: load time is fine, it is when you try to narrow results. so in my 6.5k file project, there is a skus folder in it with a show.html.erb file and a index.html.erb file in it. when i search for "skus show" there is a noticable pause while it finds the file. when i try to delete "show" and replace it with "index", there is a much longer pause. What i am thinking is that i dont care about the migrations so much (which is >1k files), and if i can scope tests (anther 1.5k files) into its own thing, hopefully that will be enough to get rid of (or reduce) the pauses

Comment: I still can't repro a slow-down.  Maybe you can send me the output of "find_interesting <rails_root>" on github?

Comment: This link [404s](https://github.com/lewang/anything-project-files/issues/1) now. Where can I find the updated repo?

Answer (score 3):

Try https://github.com/redguardtoo/find-file-in-project which use `GNU Find` or `BSD Find` to find files. Nothing can beat the speed of C!

`M-x find-file-in-project-by-selected` is the only command you need use.

I tested with 50000+ files at some stone-aged netbook without any issue.

By default it uses efficient `ivy-mode` to filter the candidate and `ido-mode` as fallback. I tested ivy-mode with **three million candidates**. Now you get the idea that Emacs Lisp itself is quick enough.

At *nix, the kernel provides cache for `find`, so if you search the files with same input, the response is instant.

Besides, the `ivy-mode` automatically cache the last search results in Emacs lisp variable `ivy-last`, so you can `M-x ivy-resume` to get the previous candidates without bothering `Find`.

You can `(setq my-cached-result ivy-last)` to store `ivy-last` into another variable. Then you can `M-x my-ivy-resume`:

```
(defun my-ivy-resume ()
  (interactive)
  (let* ((ivy-last (if my-cached-result my-cached-result ivy-last))
         (default-directory (ffip-get-project-root-directory)))
    (ivy-resume)))
```

In this way you can store last 1000 results and re-use them ;)

UPDATE 1:
Since version 6, ffip use Emacs builtin API `completing-read` instead of `ivy-read`. So ivy specific feature like `ivy-resume` is not usable, yet. You can downgrade to version 5. ffip is just single Emacs Lisp file using only Emacs builtin API, so it's easy to downgrade.

Or wait the ivy to fix the issue (see https://github.com/abo-abo/swiper/pull/2785 )

UPDATE 2:
Since version 6.1.1, I added command `ffip-find-files-resume`. It's more powerful than `ivy-resume`. For example, it can replay any previous action. `ivy-resume` can only replay last action.

Comment: `my-viy-resume gives: `The last session isn’t compatible with ‘ivy-resume’
` error , how can we fix it?

Comment: Downgrade to version 5.

Answer (score 2):

Depends what you mean by fuzzy matching. Most fuzzy matching is inherently slow, but some lightweight, pseudo-fuzzy algorithms are pretty fast.  Generally speaking, you're probably better off with a *regexp* search, not a fuzzy-match search.

Anyway, there are two parts to the question:

- Defining a project as a given set of files and directories.
- Searching through the project files & directories -- all or some

[***Icicles***](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles) can help with both:

- [Project](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Support_for_Projects) *definition*, management, etc.
- *Searching* a project or parts of it:

  - [Searching file content](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Search_Commands%2c_Overview) (and search-and-replace)
  - [Locating files](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_File-Name_Input)

Comment: looking into icicles and anything + eproject right now, will update things once I put a bit more work into it

Comment: I have a solution based on anything + rinari + my custom ruby-script that groks .gitignore to find only useful files.  It has caching, and it's lickity-split fast like slickedit textmate versions.  ;) Unfortunately, I won't have time to package it up until this weekend.  I'll post it as an answer when I do.

Comment: @event_jr that sounds absolutely delightful :D

Answer (score 2):

You can try [gpicker](http://savannah.nongnu.org/projects/gpicker). If you pass `-t guess`, it will try to figure out relevant files though scm backend such as git.

I use following snippet to find file in project, where the project root is determined by [eproject](https://github.com/jrockway/eproject).

```
(require 'iy-dep)

(defcustom iy-gpicker-cmd (executable-find "gpicker")
  "Default font"
  :type 'file
  :group 'iy-config)

(defun iy-gpicker-find-file (dir)
  (interactive
   (list
    (or (and current-prefix-arg (ido-read-directory-name "gpicker: " nil nil t))
        (and (boundp 'eproject-root) eproject-root)
        (and (not current-prefix-arg) (ido-read-directory-name "gpicker: " nil nil t))
        (if dired-directory (expand-file-name dired-directory) default-directory))))
  (when dir
    (with-temp-buffer
      (call-process iy-gpicker-cmd nil (list (current-buffer) nil) nil
                    "-t" "guess" "-m" dir)
      (cd dir)
      (dolist (file (split-string (buffer-string) "\0"))
        (unless (string-equal file "")
          (find-file file))))))

(provide 'iy-gpicker)
```

Comment: this looks very interesting. ATM im using fuzzy-file-finder, which has a dependancy on a ruby gem (which I'm not really a fan of) I'll give gpicker a try

Answer (score 0):

You probably want [IdUtils](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/IdUtils), but not being familiar with all those other *technologies* you mention I can't be sure.