# Emacs: opening any file in a large repo

Tags: emacs

### What I need

a fast/performant way to open any file under a large (`git`) repo (~9.8k files).

### Context

I have tried various solutions, like [`Textmate.el`](http://www.emacswiki.org/TextMate) and [`find-file-in-repository`](http://marmalade-repo.org/packages/find-file-in-repository). I found these solutions via previous SO questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8552659/117750) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7970537/117750) and through the [LocateFilesAnywhere EmacsWiki](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/LocateFilesAnywhere).

While both solutions work wonderfully for small-to-mdeium repos, in this case they are practically unusable. When I start typing a filename, there's a delay of several seconds before I see any result. And changing any part of the search is very laggy too.

I think the main problem is that on typing any character, `emacs`/`find-file-in-repository` starts a shell command (`git ls-files...`). I really only need to do that when I have stopped typing.

### Questions

- is there a better library out there for this use-case?
- if not, how can I introduce a delay into the command when I'm typing? i.e. while I'm in `find-file-in-repository`, I want the find-command to be invoked only when I stop typing (let's say a gap of 300ms).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

### Summary

After I received the three answers I tried them out (also answering my own question as none of the above solutions worked for me). I finally settled for `helm-ls-git`. Here's a comparison from my point-of-view:

#### [Projectile](https://github.com/bbatsov/projectile)

- took around 30 minutes to index the repo. Since projectile is not aware of `.gitignore`, the actual number of files is more like 52k.
- can be customized but something that just works (i.e. understands git) is preferable
- may need to [invalidate cache re-index](https://github.com/bbatsov/projectile#basic-setup) time to time. That would be costly and frequent since new files are added everyday to the repo.

#### [helm-cmd-t](https://github.com/lewang/helm-cmd-t)

- looked good from the description and the source.
- hard to install since it's not published in melpa/marmalade etc. More details in [this issue](https://github.com/lewang/helm-cmd-t/issues/2) I opened up.

#### GNU Global

- Didn't try as it's likely to have the same problems as Projectile (git-unaware, needs it's own "index" that may need to be maintained time to time)

[event-jr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/903943/event-jr)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14314435/117750) however opened up some more options: I was unaware of `helm` till now. Looking at [melpa](http://melpa.milkbox.net/) for helm related plugins I found the following:

#### [`helm-git`](https://github.com/maio/helm-git)

- This looked really promising
- Was easy to install with `package.el` since it's in melpa
- I also use and love `magit` - so this looked a good fit.
- However, it kept failing with a `magit-git-dir: symbol is void` kind of error. Did not dive in too much but looks like it needs to be updated. Opened up [an issue](https://github.com/maio/helm-git/issues/5)

#### [`helm-ls-git`](https://github.com/emacs-helm/helm-ls-git/blob/master/helm-ls-git.el)

- As the readme says, this is magit independent.
- Has been working wonderfully so far. Easy to install (melpa) and is fast.

Comment: wow nice comparison, I am trying the helm-ls-git. There's no documentation though. Can you provide basic howto?

Comment: Hi @eugene - sorry I noticed the comment only now. Here's my `helm` specific config: https://github.com/arnab/emacs-starter-kit/blob/master/arnab/helm-setup.el.

I also bind [`C-c h`](https://github.com/arnab/emacs-starter-kit/blob/master/arnab/keybindings.el#L55) to `heml-mini` and use that all the time.

Answer (score 2):

I use GNU global for this.  I have around 20K files in my project.  You can run 
`M-x gtags-find-file`     and type first few characters. TAB will complete  and show all the matching. You can type any characters which is part of the file name and press enter. Will show all the files that contains these characters.

I tried to use projectile for this.  But it was way too slow for the 'project indexing'.  It didn't complete the indexing even after 1.5 hours and I have to kill it!. Not sure some thing is wrong here.   GNU global is much faster and finishes the entire tag creation within 15 min.

Answer (score 1):

I use `helm-cmd-t` happily.  It will cache the file list in memory.  The cache controls are flexible enough for my needs.

I just answered your question about new repo address here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/8025310/903943

It's  https://github.com/lewang/helm-cmd-t

Comment: Thank you. So I have set up `helm` and am trying to use either `helm-git` or `helm-cmd-t`.


I installed `helm` from melpa. How do I install `helm-cmd-t`? The [install instructions](https://github.com/lewang/helm-cmd-t/blob/master/helm-cmd-t.el#L23) are very sparse and I don't know if it's telling me to put this file into the `elpa/...` dir.


Also, `helm-cmd-t` is not on marmalade/melpa. `helm-git` is, but I can't figure out, for the life of me, how to get it to work :)

Comment: I'm woefully behind the times on Emacs package management.  I'm also considering renaming the project to something more meaningful because Helm does not do flex matching as Textmate's cmd-t does.  I will clarify the installation instructions for new and add it to melpa in the next few weeks.

Answer (score 1):

You can check out [Projectile](https://github.com/bbatsov/projectile). It was basically created to provide something similar to `C-p`, but has a lot of extra project level features as well. First time project indexing will be fairly slow on such a big project, but afterwards Projectile will cache the project files (both on memory and on the hard drive) and subsequent projectile invocations should be nearly instantaneous.

Projectile also has a Helm plugin to display project files and buffers with Helm.

Comment: Tried projectile out just now. While the repo has 9.8k "recognized" (`git ls-files`) files, it actually has 52k total files.


Since projectile does not know about `.gitignore` by default it's still extremely laggy (3-5 seconds for every char I type).

Comment: Projectile supports ignoring files in a project, but currently relies on the presence of a .projectile file with a format that's pretty close to the .gitignore format.